# How to network software without a physical server - Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I've been trying to build a Client-Server programme. Once installed on a computer (Host), the host should be able to work both as the host and the server (seems easy, but that's not all).
The programme should be able to work in a network without a physical mediating server that would serve to connect the various hosts running the programme. Each host should be inteligent enough to get the Name and IP of all other hosts in the network running the programme.

-> Loosely put, like how a bluetooth enabled device works to detect other bluetooth enabled devices.

This should be working in all kinds of networks: wifi, LAN etc.

How can I implement this. Is this even possible. Any ideas are welcome - even if not exactly what I asked. Anything close is good.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If all systems you want to connect to are on the same subnet, you could use broadcasting to find the other programs.

Comment: It's on a local network - NOT the internet

Comment: Yes, broadcast, with UDP, of course. Even if your program uses TCP the 'peer discovery' must be made with UDP in order to use broadcast.

Comment: Hey [@Joachim Pileborg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) and [@user270349](http://stackoverflow.com/users/270349/user270349). Thanks for the response. Great help. I'm a network programming newbie. Will use "peer discovery" keywords for my research on this. Thank you again!

Comment: Voting to re-open - Zero Configuration Networking/Bonjour is the very obvious solution to this problem.  Like any technology, the details are reasonably complex, too much to be explained in an answer here, but those details are wrapped in a simple API.  I'll add a code sample to demonstrate this (when I'm home later) but for now I suggest this question is not too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at [Zero Configuration Networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) which is made up of three technologies:

- link-local addressing
- multicast DNS
- DNS service discovery

Basically your service process chooses a type, name and port, which it broadcasts registering itself with the other services on the network that are acting as DNS servers.  There's obviously conflict resolution and failover going on but that's it in a nutshell for the service-side of things.

Clients then broadcast requests for a service based on type and are given the registration details for the matching services allowing them to connect.

For the background have a look at [DNS Service Discovery and Zero Configuration Networking Overview](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/00100-DNSSDOverview.html) or for the reall nitty-gritty I'd recommend getting a copy of [Zero Configuration Networking - The Definative Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0043M4Z9I).

In terms of Java there's a couple of options.

Ironically [Apple's Bonjour SDK for Windows](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) contains a Java API (the one used in the book I reference above) that works well enough on Windows, though not out of the box with Linux (I gave up trying to recompile the native part of the API).

Due to this limitation with I've ended up using [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/), which isn't quite as well documented but works very well and the download has enough examples to get you going.

**EDIT**: here some code sample using jmDNS.

**Registering a Service**

This simply registers a service on the network, your server needs to be listening for TCP connections before you do this.

```
ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(
  "_exp._tcp.local.",
  "example",
  "5001",
  "Example Service"
);

JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();
jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
```

**Service Look-up**

This simply finds a service on the network, your client will still need to connect.

```
JmDNS dns = JmDNS.create();
dns.addServiceListener("_exp._tcp.local.", new ServiceListenerImpl()));
dns.list("_exp._tcp.local.", 10 * 1000);
```

And this is a basic listener.

```
private class ServiceListenerImpl implements ServiceListener
{
  @Override
  public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent serviceEvent)
  {    
    serviceEvent.getDNS().requestServiceInfo(serviceEvent.getType(), serviceEvent.getName());
  }

  @Override
  public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent)
  {
    //Handle service dropping out.
  }

  @Override
  public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent)
  {
    Socket socket = new Socket(
      new InetSocketAddress(serviceEvent.getInfo().getInetAddress(), serviceEvent.getInfo().getPort())
    ).open();

    ...
  }
}
```